# how to execute transaction in SQLitePCL

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I am trying to migrate one of my app from macOS to Windows 10 UWP.

my code to connect a sqlite

```
using SQLitePCL;
//...
SQLiteConnection connection;
connection = new SQLiteConnection(path);
```

but in the method of connection, I can not find out any command about execution of transaction

[image]

I am a newbie for Windows 10 UWP and c#

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a command like  "BEGIN TRANSACTION";

This code is one of the unit test of the project SQLitePCL:

```
            using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(this.databaseRelativePath))
            {
                using (var statement = connection.Prepare("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TestQuery;"))
                {
                    statement.Step();
                }

                using (var statement = connection.Prepare("CREATE TABLE TestQuery(id INTEGER, i INTEGER, t TEXT, r REAL);"))
                {
                    statement.Step();
                }

                var beginTransactionCommand = "BEGIN TRANSACTION";

                using (var statement = connection.Prepare(beginTransactionCommand))
                {
                    statement.Step();
                }

                foreach (var record in insertedRecords)
                {
                    var command = "INSERT INTO TestQuery(id, i, t, r) VALUES(" + record.Item1.ToString(this.invClt) + "," + record.Item2.ToString(this.invClt)
                        + ",'" + record.Item3 + "'," + record.Item4.ToString(this.invClt) + ");";

                    using (var statement = connection.Prepare(command))
                    {
                        statement.Step();
                    }
                }

                var commitTransactionCommand = "COMMIT TRANSACTION";

                using (var statement = connection.Prepare(commitTransactionCommand))
                {
                    statement.Step();
                }
}
```